# Ansible Loop with Complex When Condition

Tags: ansible, yaml

Goal: **Delete all the VMware VM snapshots that are longer than X days**

Vars in my playbook:

```
cur_time    # the current EPOCH timestamp
resrv_time  # the date (coverted to EPOCH timestamp) that a snapshot should be kept
snap_time   # the EPOCH timestamp of a snapshot
```

Workflow:

```
1. List all the snapshots of a VM with EPOCH formatted timestamp
2. Comparing the timestamp with cur_time
3. If snap_time < resrv_time, then delete the snapshot
```

Archived part:

Convert timestamp to EPOCH format wokrs great and I can also loop all the available snapshots with the "with_dict" function like this:

```
- name: Snapshot loop
  debug:
    msg: '{{ ansible_fqdn }} has {{ item.key }} with{{ snap_time }}'
  with_dict: "{{ vm_facts.instance.snapshots }}"
  vars:
    snap_time: '{{ (item.value[0:19]| to_datetime(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")).timestamp() if item.key == "creation_time" }}'
  register: snap_name
  when: item.key == "name" or item.key == "creation_time"
```

However, how can I delete the snapshot with the matching `name` and `creation_time` as well as meet the `snap_time` < `resrv_time` condition? I think I need to put a doubled when condition in the loop and call the deletion task like this:

```
- name: Remove the old snapshot(s)
  vmware_guest_snapshot:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vmware_datacentres[vcenter_hostname] }}"
    validate_certs: false
    name: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
    folder: "{{ vm_facts.instance.hw_folder }}"
    snapshot_name: "{{ snap_name }}"
    state: absent
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I think I also need to declar the `snap_name` as the global var so it will be visible to the other tasks.

P.S. here's my working playbook for removing the current(latest) snapshot:

```
- name: Find VM's facts
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vmware_datacentres[vcenter_hostname] }}"
    name: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
    validate_certs: False
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: vm_facts

- name: Snapshot details
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_fqdn }} has {{ vm_facts.instance.snapshots }} snapshots"

- name: Time debug
  debug:
    msg: "snap_time {{ snap_time }}, cur_time {{ cur_time }}, resrv_time {{ resrv_time }}"

- name: Remove Current snapshot
  vmware_guest_snapshot:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vmware_datacentres[vcenter_hostname] }}"
    validate_certs: false
    name: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
    folder: "{{ vm_facts.instance.hw_folder }}"
    snapshot_name: "{{ vm_facts.instance.snapshots.name }}"
    state: absent
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: rm_snap
  when: snap_time < resrv_time

- name: remove snapshot out
  debug:
    msg: "{{ rm_snap }}"
```

Vars:

```
vcenter_username: xxx
vcenter_password: xxx
vmware_datacentres: xxx
vcenter_hostname: xxx
TIME_IN_SECONDS: 604800
cur_time: '{{ (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")).timestamp() }}'
resrv_time: '{{ cur_time|int - TIME_IN_SECONDS }}'
```

================== Update I ===============

vm_facts:

```
"msg": {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "instance": {
        "annotation": "VM for testing   \n",
        "current_snapshot": {
            "creation_time": "2024-01-17T02:16:50.496395+00:00",
            "description": "",
            "id": 8,
            "name": "VM Snapshot 1%2f17%2f2024, 3:16:47 PM",
            "state": "poweredOn"
        },
        "customvalues": {},
        "guest_consolidation_needed": false,
        "guest_question": null,
        "guest_tools_status": "guestToolsRunning",
        "guest_tools_version": "12357",
        ...
        "snapshots": [
            {
                "creation_time": "2024-01-16T01:57:53.059670+00:00",
                "description": "",
                "id": 5,
                "name": "VM Snapshot 1%2f16%2f2024, 2:57:49 PM",
                "state": "poweredOn"
            },
            {
                "creation_time": "2024-01-17T02:16:50.496395+00:00",
                "description": "",
                "id": 8,
                "name": "VM Snapshot 1%2f17%2f2024, 3:16:47 PM",
                "state": "poweredOn"
            }
        ],
        "vimref": "vim.VirtualMachine:vm-126493",
        "vnc": {}
    }
}
```

vm_facts.instance.snapshots:

```
"msg": "testvm has [{'id': 5, 'name': 'VM Snapshot 1%2f16%2f2024, 2:57:49 PM', 'description': '', 'creation_time': '2024-01-16T01:57:53.059670+00:00', 'state': 'poweredOn'}, 

{'id': 8, 'name': 'VM Snapshot 1%2f17%2f2024, 3:16:47 PM', 'description': '', 'creation_time': '2024-01-17T02:16:50.496395+00:00', 'state': 'poweredOn'}] snapshots"
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of `vm_facts.instance` or`vm_facts.instance.snapshots` or at least the data strucutre with sample data so that one help?

Comment: Hi @U880D I've already added the debug, cheers